# Java fx - Curved arrow using QuadCurve and polygon (triangle) binding

Tags: javafx

I want to create a curved line with an arrowhead which is between two nodes (in my case these 2 nodes are StackPanes). The line needs to move accordingly as the StackPanes are dragged.

So I want something like this:
The stack panes are the circles with text and the line is a QuadCurve and the arrowhead is a polygon (triangle)

[image]

I managed to create the curved line that links between the two StackPanes nodes, and when the StackPanes are dragged using a mouse the line moves accordingly:

```
    QuadCurve line = new QuadCurve();
    line.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    line.setFill(null);
    line.setStrokeWidth(2);
    line.startXProperty().bind(vertexClickedOn.layoutXProperty().add(vertexClickedOn.translateXProperty()).add(vertexClickedOn.widthProperty().divide(2))); 
    line.startYProperty().bind(vertexClickedOn.layoutYProperty().add(vertexClickedOn.translateYProperty()).add(vertexClickedOn.heightProperty().divide(2)));
    line.endXProperty().bind(vertexTo.layoutXProperty().add(vertexTo.translateXProperty()).add(vertexTo.widthProperty().divide(2)));
    line.endYProperty().bind(vertexTo.layoutYProperty().add(vertexTo.translateYProperty()).add(vertexTo.heightProperty().divide(2)));

    line.controlXProperty().bind((line.startXProperty().add(line.endXProperty()).divide(2)));
    line.controlYProperty().bind((line.startYProperty().add(line.endYProperty()).divide(2)).add(150));
```

VertexClickedOn is a StackPane and is where the start of the line starts, vertexTo is the other StackPane and is where the line ends (and where the arrowhead should be).

To make an arrowhead I created this triangle and tried to bind it to the line like this:

```
Polygon arrowHead = new Polygon();
arrowHead.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
0.0, 0.0,
20.0, 10.0,
10.0, 20.0 });
arrowHead.setFill(Color.BLACK);

arrowHead.layoutXProperty().bind(line.endXProperty().add(line.translateXProperty()));
arrowHead.layoutYProperty().bind(line.endYProperty().add(line.translateYProperty()));
```

However, the triangle is going underneath the StackPane and also doesn't move properly when dragging the StackPanes with the mouse.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.